# Same element has different pixel sizes on different loading points

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having a bad time guessing why one element has different pixel sizes depending on the set of rules loaded. Apparently the element has always the same font-size **6em**, which is translated to an height of 96px. But after some other rules has been loaded the same font-size is translated to an height of 86px. Here are two snapshots of the computed styles:

Font size when page is loading
[image: Font size when page is loading]
Font size when page has loaded fully
[image: Font size when page has loaded fully]

How can I track down to the rules that makes this happen?
Regards

Comment: Go through your CSS and make sure that your `font-size` property for this element is not overridden. Also check if you have set the `font-size` for any other parent element as this property is inherited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An EM is not a fixed unit of measurement, it's a relative size. The origin of "EM" is literally the width of the letter "M" in a particular font. In digital typography, an EM is relative to the base font size. So, what you're seeing is an illustration of the "cascading" nature of CSS.

When initially loaded the base font is set either at a percent or a fixed size (e.g.: 12px, 14px, 100%, etc.) Then, when additional styles are loaded, the size of the font that your `#TP_splash_screen` is inheriting from is altered to be something smaller, so the 6em value is now smaller.

Consider this example:

```
body{
    font-size: 12px;
}

#TP_splash_screen{
    font-size: 6em;
}

.container{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

If you use `#TP_splash_screen` as an element that is the direct child of the `body` element, then your font will be 6em of 12px (6 times the size of a 12px "M"). If you use `#TP_splash_screen` as an element that is a child of a `container` element, then your font will be 6em of 10px (6 times the size of a 10px "M").

EM's are a great unit of measurement for working with flexible, responsive layouts, they are not fixed units of measure.

Comment: That solves my doubts totally. Thank you very much. Probably when the full page is loaded any random css rule sets the font-size of the body to a relatively small pixel size. I can deduct that now that I fully understand that the em size is relative to the container, and not the full document..

Comment: Glad it helped @Danielo515!